# Laravel 4 application is giving error while running as a facebook app

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am creating a facebook application in Laravel 4, the problem is it is giving me following error while running as a facebook application

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

but the same thing is working fine out of facebook.I followed this tutorial
http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/integrating-facebook-login-into-laravel-application/

Following is my routes.php

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
Route::get('/', function() {
$facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
$params = array(
    'redirect_uri' => url('/login/fb/callback'),
    'scope' => 'email,publish_stream',
);
return Redirect::to($facebook->getLoginUrl($params));
}); 

Route::get('login/fb/callback', function() {
$code = Input::get('code');
if (strlen($code) == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error communicating with Facebook');

$facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
$uid = $facebook->getUser();

if ($uid == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error');

$me = $facebook->api('/me');

return Redirect::to('home')->with('user', $me);

});
```

Edit: I have checked chrome console and getting this error

Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=327652603940310&redirect_ur…7736c22f906b948d7eddc6a2ad0&sdk=php-sdk-3.2.3&scope=email%2Cpublish_stream' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Comment: `Route::get('login/fb/callback', function() {` should be `Route::get('/login/fb/callback', function() {` I think

Comment: The error is that the controller isn't being found, so when on local it works fine as domain.com/ + "login/fb/callback" works, but when on Facebook it needs the "/" in front

Comment: @We0 still getting the same error.

Comment: The slash has nothing to do with it. Laravel is smart enough to know that.

Comment: @DevendraVerma I just finished building the exact same thing and also looked at that guide, didn't work for me, so I used this: http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/IDProvider_info_Facebook.html

Answer (score 2):

Put this somewhere inside **bootstrap/start.php**:

```
$app->forgetMiddleware('Illuminate\Http\FrameGuard');
```

You can read this post:
http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=65620

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your callback to be `Route::post` not `Route::get`. If my memory serves me correctly, Facebook places a POST request, not a GET request.

```
<?php
Route::get('login/fb/callback', function() {
    $code = Input::get('code');

    if (strlen($code) == 0) {
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error communicating with Facebook');
    }

    $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($uid == 0) {
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error');
    }

    $me = $facebook->api('/me');

    return Redirect::to('home')->with('user', $me);

});
```

After looking at the link that you sent, the error actually tells you what is wrong.

```
REQUEST_URI /
REQUEST_METHOD  POST
```

Loading that page is making a POST request to /, and like I suggested above, you'll need to change the route for the index to `Route::post`.

Comment: `Route::any()` can also be used

Comment: Route any would mean that it's open for PUT, DELETE and I think PATCH, which aren't needed.

Comment: thanks for reply @ollieread but still I am getting the same error for your reference this is the fb app link https://apps.facebook.com/adadadsgs/

Comment: Updated my answer, pretty sure I sussed it out.

Comment: @ollieread now error has disappeared but now I am seeing a blank page.

Comment: @ollieread it is working fine on my local installation but not inside facebook

Comment: Then there's a problem somewhere deeper in your code.